# Get exception details from a Azure Monitor Workbook

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

In application insights I can click on an exception and find nicely formatted information about it if I click on it.
This could look like this:

[image]

I would like to archive the same in an Azure Workbook.  Here I can display all my exceptions with the KQL Term "Exceptions".
With the column settings I was hoping to be able to create a link to the Application insights page that shows me the same result like in the picture above.
I use this configuration:

[image]

Now I have a link, but when I click it there is just an empty pane:

[image]

Is there anything I misunderstand?
How do I need to configure my column settings to get a direct link to the Exception details like in clicking on the same item in Application Insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not super obvious, the info bubble for the link settings shows:

[image: column is expected to be an itemId]

> The value in the column is expected to be an `itemId` of an exception telemetry item.

So as long as your query returns the `itemId` field, you can map that in the column settings:

[image: item id settings]

(also, iirc, if the query returns a `timestamp` column, the details view will try to narrow down its search to just use a range around that time instead of trying to query a larger amount of time to find an item with that id)

**Edit to add**: if you are using thee Log Analytics based schema, `AppExceptions` the field is there but missing from documentation and the schema, there is an `_ItemId` field that is this field.  I'm working with the App Insights/ Log Analytics teams to get this properly documented there.

Also, even if you're using the log analytics based app insights, you can also always query through the "app insights" resource and use the app insights schema the "old" way as well.  (unless you're doing something specific in log analytics that the AI based way doesn't have?)

example:

- left is query against app insights schema, with `exceptions` table and `itemId` column
- right is query against logs schema, with `AppExceptions` table and `_ItemId` field, returning the same exact item by that id value. you can seee that the `_ItemId` field shows red squiggles like it isn't valid, but that is incorrect, you'll get the right row if you run the query.

[image: screenshot showing same query 2 ways]

Comment: Thanks, that seems plausible. However, a field "itemId" is not returned if I query "AppExceptions". I have "OperationId", "IKey", "_ResourceId" and within "Properties" also a "TraceId". But no itemId...??

Comment: what table are you querying? I don't think `AppExceptions` is a standard app insights schema table (`exceptions` would be?)  the app insights view is querying all that data from its own tables again, given the itemId, so if it isn't an app insights table, the exception details view won't be able to find it?

Comment: I think I am using "AppExceptions", because my application insights is using a workspace. Here the names changed... so in a workspace the "itemId" maybe does not exist anymore?

Comment: updated the answer, the field is there, `_ItemId`, it is just missing/hidden in the schema.  Working with the AI and Logs teams internally to find out WHY it isn't in the schema.

Comment: Mhh... interesting. I cannot find any "_ItemId" field, but it is probably hidden in the background and cannot be queried yet. I will just accept that I still need to wait a while until its supported what I want to do. Thanks man :)

Comment: if you use it in a query, it should work, though.  it might show as red underline in the logs view, or might not autocomplete, but it does exist and the query will work.  added a screenshot above that is the query that returns the same item either from the appinsights or logs based schema in the same resource/workspace