# Get exception details from Azure Monitor Workbook that deals with multiple app insight instances

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am working on creating a workbook that provides an umbrella view over multiple app insight instances. Our solution has many microservices (Azure functions) each having its own app insight instance. Aim of this workbook is to provide a health status for the whole app by surfacing up errors across app insight instances in to a single view.

I have used the "Failure Analysis" template to set this up. User is able to select different app insight instances at the top and the views will filter based on that. There's a view that shows exception counts with trends like this. Each error may belong to different App Insight instances.

[image]

When you click on a line item all instances of that error will be shown in a following view like this

[image]

I use the following query to load it

```
let row = dynamic({Row});
let req = requests
| where '{Row}' == '{}' or (row.Kind == 'Application' and row.Id 
    == appName) or (row.Kind == 'Request' and row.Id ==    
    strcat(appName, "::", name))
| where success == "False";

 let errors = exceptions
 | where appName == appName 
 | where timestamp between({TimeRange:start}..{TimeRange:end});

 errors
 | join req on operation_Id
 | project operation_Id, itemId, timestamp,requestName=name, 
        exception=type, method, outerMessage, innermostMessage, 
        details, appName
```

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562247/get-exception-details-from-a-azure-monitor-workbook) [Get exception details from a Azure Monitor Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562247/get-exception-details-from-a-azure-monitor-workbook), the itemId is available and I try to link it to the "Exception Details" view. Please note that these errors can come from one of many App Insight instances based on what gets selected at the previous view.

I have configured the item Id and appName columns as follows using Link renderer and Automatic renderer.

[image]
[image]

However the link always directs to one specific app insight instance (Not the one associated with the error) and hence the error won't get loaded. Is it possible to load the "Detail Views" across App Insight instances using this technique? If not what could be other avenues?
[image]

Comment: when using the link renderen you cannot acces other application insights instances, I once had the same issue. See my answer for the solution I went for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application insights is [workspace based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource), each telemetry item has a field `_ResourceId` that contains a link to the resource, for example

> /subscriptions/c8vfbeab-a5a67-4272-aa6e-4c9f4142e962/resourcegroups/rg-my-resource-group/providers/microsoft.insights/components/my-ai-resource

You can use this a part of the url to create a deep link to the details page of the Application Insights resource of the telemetry with the specified item id. Take this query for example:

```
exceptions
| take 1
| extend portalUrl = strcat("https://portal.azure.com/#blade/AppInsightsExtension/BladeRedirect/BladeName/searchV1/ResourceId/", url_encode(_ResourceId), "/BladeInputs/%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%22availabilityResults%22%2C%22requests%22%2C%22exceptions%22%2C%22pageViews%22%2C%22traces%22%2C%22customEvents%22%2C%22dependencies%22%5D%2C%22timeContextWhereClause%22%3A%22%7C%20where%20timestamp%20%3E%20datetime(%5C%222022-02-12T12%3A55%3A02.739Z%5C%22)%20and%20timestamp%20%3C%20datetime(%5C%222022-03-14T12%3A55%3A02.739Z%5C%22)%22%2C%22filterWhereClause%22%3A%22%7C%20where%20*%20has%20%5C%22a1a20ad1a12ff348a852288a4d9953a5%5C%22%7C%20order%20by%20timestamp%20desc%22%2C%22originalParams%22%3A%7B%22eventTypes%22%3A%5B%7B%22value%22%3A%22availabilityResult%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22availabilityResults%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Availability%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22request%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22requests%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Request%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22exception%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22exceptions%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Exception%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22pageView%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22pageViews%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Page%20View%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22trace%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22traces%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Trace%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22customEvent%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22customEvents%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Custom%20Event%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22dependency%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22dependencies%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Dependency%22%7D%5D%2C%22timeContext%22%3A%7B%22durationMs%22%3A2592000000%7D%2C%22filter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22searchPhrase%22%3A%7B%22originalPhrase%22%3A%22", itemId,"%22%2C%22_tokens%22%3A%5B%7B%22conjunction%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22a1a20ad1a12ff348a852288a4d9953a5%22%2C%22isNot%22%3Afalse%2C%22kql%22%3A%22%20*%20has%20%5C%22a1a20ad1a12ff348a852288a4d9953a5%5C%22%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D")
| project timestamp,  problemId, itemId, portalUrl
```

If you create a workbook and render a table based on the query above you have to modify the itemId column to be a link like this:

[image]

Clicking the itemId column it should open the correct Application Insights resource details page:

[image]

[image]

Now, I hope this give you enough clues to extend your own queries by including the deep link url in your query output.

For completeness, this is the full workbook Gallery Template:

```json
{
  "version": "Notebook/1.0",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": 3,
      "content": {
        "version": "KqlItem/1.0",
        "query": "exceptions\n| take 1\n| extend portalUrl = strcat(\"https://portal.azure.com/#blade/AppInsightsExtension/BladeRedirect/BladeName/searchV1/ResourceId/\", url_encode(_ResourceId), \"/BladeInputs/%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%22availabilityResults%22%2C%22requests%22%2C%22exceptions%22%2C%22pageViews%22%2C%22traces%22%2C%22customEvents%22%2C%22dependencies%22%5D%2C%22timeContextWhereClause%22%3A%22%7C%20where%20timestamp%20%3E%20datetime(%5C%222022-02-12T12%3A55%3A02.739Z%5C%22)%20and%20timestamp%20%3C%20datetime(%5C%222022-03-14T12%3A55%3A02.739Z%5C%22)%22%2C%22filterWhereClause%22%3A%22%7C%20where%20*%20has%20%5C%22a1a20ad1a12ff348a852288a4d9953a5%5C%22%7C%20order%20by%20timestamp%20desc%22%2C%22originalParams%22%3A%7B%22eventTypes%22%3A%5B%7B%22value%22%3A%22availabilityResult%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22availabilityResults%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Availability%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22request%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22requests%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Request%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22exception%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22exceptions%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Exception%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22pageView%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22pageViews%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Page%20View%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22trace%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22traces%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Trace%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22customEvent%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22customEvents%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Custom%20Event%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%22dependency%22%2C%22tableName%22%3A%22dependencies%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Dependency%22%7D%5D%2C%22timeContext%22%3A%7B%22durationMs%22%3A2592000000%7D%2C%22filter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22searchPhrase%22%3A%7B%22originalPhrase%22%3A%22\", itemId,\"%22%2C%22_tokens%22%3A%5B%7B%22conjunction%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22a1a20ad1a12ff348a852288a4d9953a5%22%2C%22isNot%22%3Afalse%2C%22kql%22%3A%22%20*%20has%20%5C%22a1a20ad1a12ff348a852288a4d9953a5%5C%22%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D\")\n| project timestamp,  problemId, itemId, portalUrl",
        "size": 1,
        "timeContext": {
          "durationMs": 86400000
        },
        "queryType": 0,
        "resourceType": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "gridSettings": {
          "formatters": [
            {
              "columnMatch": "problemId",
              "formatter": 1,
              "formatOptions": {
                "linkColumn": "portalUrl",
                "linkTarget": "Url"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "name": "query - 2"
    }
  ],
  "fallbackResourceIds": [
    "/subscriptions/4547474-1a67-4272-aa6e-4c9f4142e269/resourceGroups/rg-resourcegroup-prod/providers/microsoft.insights/components/appi-demo-prod"
  ],
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/schema/workbook.json"
}
```

Comment: Hey Pete, thanks a lot. This worked perfectly for me. I was at a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like from a quick perusal of the code, that if you *also* have an `appName` column in the row where `itemId` is, it will try to look in the resource list used in the query to try to find a resource with that same name, and if not, just take the first one it can find?

but i see that you have `appName` there, but i'm not sure the rest of the configuration from your step?  are you also using all of the resources in the query?

Comment: Hi John - thanks for your response.

Yes, I do have `appName` in the query. I have updated the screenshot to show it more clearly now. 

Not sure if I fully understand what you mean by "Are you also using all of the resources in the query". What ever App Insight instances the user selects will be the scope of the query. 

I have also updated the question with the column configuration for the ItemId and AppName.

Comment: To describe it a bit more, if the user selects 2 app insight instances from the top (Say 'a' and 'b') and then tries to drill down in to an error from the second instance (b), she will be directed to the first app insight instance (a) when clicked on the item Id (Instead of the second instance where the error is actually located). 

In fact user is always directed to the first instance, irrespective of what's there in the 'appName' column. Should the 'appName' column be using a 'special' setting to facilitate this behaviour? Neither "Automatic" and "Text" rendering worked.